# How to synchronize Observables and offload UI Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive

I have two simple observing handlers with a subscription to the same source. However both subscriptions operate on different types. I want them to keep the order of the observable source (Subject()). I tried it with the Synchronize() extension but I don't found a way to get this work as expected.

**Here is my Unit Test Code:**

```
[Test]
public void TestObserveOn()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    var source = new Subject<object>();
    var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    using (source.ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default).Synchronize(source).OfType<int>().Subscribe(
        o =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received {1} on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, o);
                int sleep = 3000 / o; // just to simulate longer processing
                Thread.Sleep(sleep);
                Console.WriteLine("Handled  {1} on threadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, o);
            },
        () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                are.Set();
            }))
    using (source.ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default).Synchronize(source).OfType<double>().Subscribe(
                    o =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Received {1} on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, o);
                        Console.WriteLine("Handled  {1} on threadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, o);
                    },
                    () =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    }))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Subscribed on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        source.OnNext(1);
        source.OnNext(1.1);
        source.OnNext(2);
        source.OnNext(2.1);
        source.OnNext(3);
        source.OnNext(3.1);
        source.OnCompleted();

        Console.WriteLine("Finished on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        are.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

**Resulting output of the test code:**

```
Starting on threadId:10
Subscribed on threadId:10
Finished on threadId:10
Received 1 on threadId:11
Handled  1 on threadId: 11
Received 1,1 on threadId:12
Handled  1,1 on threadId: 12
Received 2,1 on threadId:12
Handled  2,1 on threadId: 12
Received 3,1 on threadId:12
Handled  3,1 on threadId: 12
Received 2 on threadId:11
Handled  2 on threadId: 11
OnCompleted on threadId:12
Received 3 on threadId:11
Handled  3 on threadId: 11
OnCompleted on threadId:11
```

As you can see the order is different to the input. I want to synchronize both subscriptions, so that the order is the same as for the input.

**The output should be**

```
Starting on threadId:10
Subscribed on threadId:10
Finished on threadId:10
Received 1 on threadId:11
Handled  1 on threadId: 11
Received 1,1 on threadId:12
Handled  1,1 on threadId: 12
Received 2 on threadId:11
Handled  2 on threadId: 11
Received 2,1 on threadId:12
Handled  2,1 on threadId: 12
Received 3 on threadId:11
Handled  3 on threadId: 11
Received 3,1 on threadId:12
Handled  3,1 on threadId: 12
OnCompleted on threadId:11
OnCompleted on threadId:12
```

(Completion order is not that important for me).

**EDIT:**

I also tried the following:

```
[Test]
public void TestObserveOn()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    var source = new Subject<object>();
    var taskSchedulerPair = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair();
    var exclusiveTaskFactory = new TaskFactory(taskSchedulerPair.ExclusiveScheduler);
    var exclusiveScheduler = new TaskPoolScheduler(exclusiveTaskFactory);
    var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    using (source.ObserveOn(exclusiveScheduler).OfType<int>().Subscribe(
        o =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received {1} on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, o);
                int sleep = 3000 / o;
                Thread.Sleep(sleep);
                Console.WriteLine("Handled  {1} on threadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, o);
            },
        () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                are.Set();
            }))
    using (source.ObserveOn(exclusiveScheduler).OfType<double>().Subscribe(
                    o =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Received {1} on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, o);
                        Console.WriteLine("Handled  {1} on threadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, o);
                    },
                    () =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                        are.Set();
                    }))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Subscribed on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        source.OnNext(1);
        source.OnNext(1.1);
        source.OnNext(2);
        source.OnNext(2.1);
        source.OnNext(3);
        source.OnNext(3.1);
        source.OnCompleted();

        Console.WriteLine("Finished on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        are.WaitOne();
        are.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

But the output is still wrong:

```
Starting on threadId:10
Subscribed on threadId:10
Finished on threadId:10
Received 1 on threadId:4
Handled  1 on threadId: 4
Received 2 on threadId:4
Handled  2 on threadId: 4
Received 3 on threadId:4
Handled  3 on threadId: 4
OnCompleted on threadId:4
Received 1,1 on threadId:4
Handled  1,1 on threadId: 4
Received 2,1 on threadId:4
Handled  2,1 on threadId: 4
Received 3,1 on threadId:4
Handled  3,1 on threadId: 4
OnCompleted on threadId:4
```

... as you can see it is not in the order of the OnNext() calls.

This is especially important when using types with a meaning like create and then afterwards doing several updates... what to do if the update is before the create? If the order is not guaranteed you might have a problem or need to queue the "future" events until their predecessor is in sync with the state to change.
You need something like an increasing version/order number to use this as ordering criteria and find "holes" and queue the successors until they are in line again.

**2nd EDIT**
... to be more close to my problem and get out of the Test Case Theory:

I want a simple interface that is easy to use with RX filtering functionality:

```
public interface ICommandBus // or to say Aggregator pattern
{
    void Send<T>(T command) where T : ICommand; // might be something like Task<Result> Send<T>(T command) to know the system has accepted the command

    IObservable<T> Stream<T>() where T : ICommand;
}

public class CommandBus : ICommandBus, IDisposable
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger<CommandBus>();

    private readonly HashSet<Type> registrations = new HashSet<Type>();

    private readonly Subject<ICommand> stream = new Subject<ICommand>();

    private readonly IObservable<ICommand> notifications;

    private bool disposed;

    public CommandBus()
    {
        // hmm, this is a problem!? how to sync?
        this.notifications = this.stream.SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default);

    }

    public IObservable<T> Stream<T>() where T : ICommand
    {
        var observable = this.notifications.OfType<T>();
        return new ExclusiveObservableWrapper<T>(
            observable,
            t => this.registrations.Add(t),
            t => this.registrations.Remove(t));
    }

    public void Send<T>(T command) where T : ICommand
    {
        if (command == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("command");
        }

        if (!this.registrations.Contains(typeof(T)))
        {
            throw new NoCommandHandlerSubscribedException();
        }

        Log.Debug(logm => logm("Sending command of type {0}.", typeof(T).Name));

        this.stream.OnNext(command);
    }

    //public async Task SendAsync<T>(T command) where T : ICommand
    //{
    //    if (command == null)
    //    {
    //        throw new ArgumentNullException("command");
    //    }

    //    if (!this.registrations.Contains(typeof(T)))
    //    {
    //        throw new NoCommandHandlerSubscribedException();
    //    }

    //    Log.Debug(logm => logm("Sending command of type {0}.", typeof(T)));

    //    this.stream.OnNext(command);

    //    await this.stream.Where(item => ReferenceEquals(item, command));
    //}

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                this.stream.Dispose();
            }
        }

        this.disposed = true;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class CommandAlreadySubscribedException : Exception
    {
        internal CommandAlreadySubscribedException(Type type)
            : base(string.Format("Tried to subscribe handler for command of type {0} but there was already a subscribtion. More than one handler at time is not allowed.", type))
        {
        }

        protected CommandAlreadySubscribedException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context)
        {
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class NoCommandHandlerSubscribedException : Exception
    {
        public NoCommandHandlerSubscribedException()
        {
        }

        public NoCommandHandlerSubscribedException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }

        public NoCommandHandlerSubscribedException(string message, Exception innerException)
            : base(message, innerException)
        {
        }

        protected NoCommandHandlerSubscribedException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context)
        {
        }
    }

    private class ExclusiveObservableWrapper<T> : IObservable<T> where T : ICommand
    {
        private readonly IObservable<T> observable;

        private readonly Func<Type, bool> register;

        private readonly Action<Type> unregister;

        internal ExclusiveObservableWrapper(IObservable<T> observable, Func<Type, bool> register, Action<Type> unregister)
        {
            this.observable = observable;
            this.register = register;
            this.unregister = unregister;
        }

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
        {
            var subscription = this.observable.Subscribe(observer);
            var type = typeof(T);

            if (!this.register(type))
            {
                observer.OnError(new CommandAlreadySubscribedException(type));
            }

            return Disposable.Create(
                () =>
                {
                    subscription.Dispose();
                    this.unregister(type);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

If I can't guarantee that the commands are in the order (as given) then they (might) make no sense. (update before create)

The ICommandBus is used from the UI/Presentation layer that wants to call the according handler for the command (without need to knowing the handler).

I want to simply offload the chain to a separate thread.

Command -> Bus -> Command Handler -> Domain Model -> Event -> Event Handler -> Read Model

This needs to keep the commands in order of appearance.

I thought RX is capable of doing that with just some "magic lines". But as far as I can see now I have to do it again with own thread handling. :-(

Comment: Im new to RX. I hoped there is a way to use it for offloading but keep the series even with multiple subscribers.

Comment: Not if you are using a scheduler that allows concurrency. Try `EventLoopScheduler` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have the wrong understanding of what `.Synchronize()` does. Its sole purpose is to take an observable that is producing overlapping or out of place messages (i.e. A `OnCompleted` before a `OnNext` or multiple `OnError`) and making sure that they follow the `OnNext*(OnError|OnCompleted)` behaviour contract. It's about making a rogue observable play nice.

Now, since we can ignore that, as your sample input is a well behaved observable, then you can see that by calling `.ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)` you are making your observable jump threads - which can easily lead to observables being consumed at different rates - which is what is happening here.

You have subscribed to the `source` twice so you can't stop the behave you're seeing given the way you are introducing concurrency.

Given your previous question ([How to await finished IObserver call including observing subscriber calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988412/how-to-await-finished-iobserver-call-including-observing-subscriber-calls)) you seem hell-bent on using Rx to add concurrency, but then force it somehow to remove it. You really should be in the mindset of unleashing Rx to do its thing and not nobble it.

**EDIT by @Beachwalker:**

Enigmativity gave the right answer to my question ***within its comment to this answer***.

I have to use the [EventLoopScheduler](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html). So I accept this as correct answer.

For completeness. Here is the code that works:

```
[Test]
public void TestObserveOn()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    var source = new Subject<object>();
    var exclusiveScheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();
    var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    using (source.ObserveOn(exclusiveScheduler).OfType<int>().Subscribe(
        o =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received {1} on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, o);
                int sleep = 3000 / o;
                Thread.Sleep(sleep);
                Console.WriteLine("Handled  {1} on threadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, o);
            },
        () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                are.Set();
            }))
    using (source.ObserveOn(exclusiveScheduler).OfType<double>().Subscribe(
                    o =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(
                                "Received {1} on threadId:{0}",
                                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                                o);
                            Console.WriteLine(
                                "Handled  {1} on threadId: {0}",
                                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                                o);
                        },
                    () =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                        are.Set();
                    }))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Subscribed on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        source.OnNext(1);
        source.OnNext(1.1);
        source.OnNext(2);
        source.OnNext(2.1);
        source.OnNext(3);
        source.OnNext(3.1);
        source.OnCompleted();

        Console.WriteLine("Finished on threadId:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        are.WaitOne();
        are.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I am forced to put my own thread management around RX to offload from UI task? Hmm, disappointing. I thought RX could help in this typical case, too. It seems @VMAtm is close to a solution. I just want to move the whole to an other thread. I can't believe there is no solution to this problem (which is easy in "old school coding", but needs too much code from my point of view).

Comment: @Beachwalker - No, not at all. Rx is superb at abstracting away threading concerns. You sample code is very abstract. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Thx for trying to help. I edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: I don't want to add concurrency between within the observable processing, I want to move the whole to be processed on another thread using RX tools. Yes, hell-bent. ;-) I already know the "manual" way of doing this without RX, but I hope there is a way using RX.

Comment: The simple answer is to use an `EventLoopScheduler` as your scheduler. Try that.

Comment: Thanks for the right simple answer... it worked. ;-) I didn't noticed that this Scheduler will do offloading, thought it will run on the same thread as the UI and will use some "magical" messages in the message pump.

Comment: @Beachwalker - The `EventLoopScheduler` is a single-threaded (non-UI thread) scheduler. It is its own event loop separate to the UI.

Comment: ... seems like the thing I was searching for, like the good old BackgroundWorker class but for RX ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You create a two different tasks for your `source`, based on filter by type of source next member.

You handle the messages **in parallel**, as you can see from the thread ids. This provides you the better performance, but provide you **no guarantee** for an order of handling the `source`. So, if you need a sequential handle for your objects, you either have to rewrite your code for a sequential execution (which will degrade your performance) or to use other scheduler for test purposes.

Currently you are using `TaskPoolScheduler.Default`, which simply use the default thread pool. So you can provide [a new scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.concurrency.taskpoolscheduler.taskpoolscheduler.aspx). You can provide it a new implementation by yourself, but I think that the most easiest way is to use [`ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair.aspx) class to provide an exclusive scheduler to handle your `source` in the same order you provide a values.

Your code could be something like this:

```
var taskSchedulerPair = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair();
var exclusiveTaskFactory = new TaskFactory(taskSchedulerPair.ExclusiveScheduler );
var exclusiveScheduler = new TaskPoolScheduler(exclusiveTaskFactory);
using (source.ObserveOn(exclusiveScheduler)...
```

**Update**:

As in other's post been said, the correct way to handle events like that is [`EventLoopScheduler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.concurrency.eventloopscheduler.aspx) class.

Comment: Thx for your help. I tried your suggestion... but it didn't work as expected. See my edit.

Comment: Oh, that's unexpected for me. So it seems that you have either to write additional logic for sync up the observers. Did you try to add the `Synchronize` method call?

Comment: Yes, but it does not seem to affect something. @Enigmativity also said Synchronize() is not the right tool for that. (Even though I don't know why you should reorder OnNext() and OnError() in an observable stream as he gave as example).